# Allow a certain set of domain names corrisponding ip with resolution and whitelisting on the fly

Tags: linux, scripting, cron, dns, firewall

I'm trying to setup a firewall config for a specific machine. The firewall is configured to block all traffic except for a certain set of allowed IPs.

Today I was asked to put on a teamviewer service and everything is fine however teamviewer uses a certain set of **router*.teamviewer.com** as intermediate machines allowing connections through nats.

Given that **they doesn't release publically a set of ip or cidr of their servers**, aswell the fact they change time to time their servers based on agreements with various providers, they have not very fixed addresses.

What comes to my mind are 2 approaches:

1. Get a list of all teamviewer subdomains like **.teamviewer.com* and resolve the corrisponding dns entry, hence whitelist these addresses. However I searched on SE website and it appears that the only mode to get a list of subdomains is actually bruteforcing them ? O_o seriously? no **DNS query** can be cast to a **DNS SOA zone** in order to get all the corrisponding subdomains?
2. The other option could be intercept all the DNS queries containing **.teamviewer.com*, resolve the IP via DNS query and whitelist the ip on the fly, but I'm not sure if this could be really doable all at once. I'm not sure if it's possible intercept the dns packet, make it to wait, resolve the ip before the actual dns resolution so that once the original query result is returned back the corrisponding ip address is already being whitelisted. And this doesn't take in account the possibility that DNS server play fun and round robin or load balance the traffic responding each time with a different ip address.

There are better possible solutions to this approach?

Comment: option 2 might work if there's a DNS request. If the protocol passes an IP address instead of a DNS address, even this won't happen. Of course integration would be difficult: the DNS server would have to communicate with the firewall (and count on retries of the protocol rather than "buffering" it).

Comment: Also, it appears that many such addresses have a xxx.router.teamviewer.com reverse DNS: this becomes much more simple but at the same time resource hog if it's actually always the case: check reverse dns for each destination when it's on the dedicated port (to be done by the firewall).

Answer (score 1):

With `dig`, you can transfer a whole zone:

```
dig AXFR my_domain @my_dns_server
```

Note that your DNS must allow this with an option like:

```
allow-transfer { trusted_ip; localhost;};
```

Comment: The use of transfer is for the second solution proposed ?

Comment: It is about the first solution. You said that zone transfer are not possible. I prove this wrong (if we can configure the DNS), then it is possible to scan a zone an initialize a firewall config. But this way is not really dynamic. Perhaps a DNS query for the serial number in SOA may tell you if the zone has change. We can have one such request per minute… and if there is a change, process the zone transfer and recompute the firewall setting.

Comment: I see, but it seems that teamviewer.com DNS does not allow the AXFR, dig says: transfer failed.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t aware that you did not control the DNS. The zone transfer is normally restricted to server DNS which serve the same domain. This prevent abuses.